# Error in Insert Value "answer" in CDR Database Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, telephony, cdr

This error occurs to me sometimes when the call is hung up. The rest is saved normally. I expose a bad record and a good one

> [Dec 6 19:47:19] ERROR[31348][C-00000045]: cdr_mysql.c:349 mysql_log:
>   Failed to insert into database: (1292) Incorrect datetime value:
>   ‘SIP/sip_lbascunan/961258985,160,wWTt’ for column ‘answer’ at row 1

Good Row

> ‘1575675020.46’, ‘1575675020.46’, ‘“343591171” <343591171>’,
>   ‘343591171’, ‘101961258985’, ‘engine’, ‘SIP/asterisk-63-0000002e’,
>   ‘SIP/opsmovil-0000002f’, ‘Hangup’, ‘’, ‘2019-12-06 20:30:20’, NULL,
>   ‘2019-12-06 20:30:20’, ‘0’, ‘0’, ‘NO ANSWER’, ‘3’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘55’, ‘’

Bad Row

> ‘1575674496.30’, ‘1575674496.30’, ‘“SISTEMAS” <1084>’, ‘1084’,
>   ‘90962108827’, ‘lbascunan’, ‘SIP/1084-0000001e’,
>   ‘SIP/sip_lbascunan-0000001f’, ‘Dial’,
>   ‘SIP/sip_lbascunan/962108827,160,wWTt’, ‘2019-12-06 20:21:36’,
>   ‘SIP/sip_lbascunan/962108827,160,wWTt’, ‘2019-12-06 20:22:00’, ‘24’,
>   ‘0’, ‘NO ANSWER’, ‘3’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘35’, ‘’

I had to change the Answer field from Varchar to Datetime so that I could save.

This is my Table CDR

```
CREATE TABLE `cdr` (
  `uniqueid` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `linkedid` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `clid` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `src` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dst` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dcontext` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `channel` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dstchannel` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastapp` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastdata` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `answer` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `billsec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `disposition` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `amaflags` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `accountcode` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `userfield` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sequence` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `peeraccount` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uniqueid`),
  KEY `start` (`start`),
  KEY `dst` (`dst`),
  KEY `accountcode` (`accountcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incorrect quatation.
Check special symbols in  callerid(name).

Anyway it is nothing to answer. Just bad system design and no check for sql injection.